# VS2012 Linker progression bar not showing?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

In VS2012 (and possibly other versions):

> :NOSTATUS | :STATUS (optional) Specifies whether the linker displays a
>   progress indicator that shows what percentage of the link is complete.
>   By default, this status information is not displayed.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx)

I have enabled this progression bar in the Linker (All options) section, but do not see any progression bar in the build window. Should I be looking elsewhere? I am assuming it would be some type of indicator giving a linker % completed?